# how to call rest service from templates in django from seriliazers.py and views.py in django rest framework

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I have created the api endpoints for locking and unlocking the user in django with DRF and seriliazers.

I want to call this rest services in my django template for locking the user and unlocking the user.

here is the code in templates

`<a href="{% url 'rest-auth/rest_lock/' %}?username={{user.username}}"  class="table-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" /></a>
{% else %}
<a href="{% url 'rest-auth/rest_unlock/' %}?username={{user.username}}" class="table-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase" /></a>`

The problem is I am calling the above web service but I am not able to lock the user with that web service.

Here is the code for rest services.

In seriliazers:

```
class LockUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
"""
User model w/o password
"""
class Meta:
   model = UserModel
   #fields=('username')
   exclude = ('password','email','last_login','is_superuser','is_active','first_name','last_name','is_staff','date_joined','groups','user_permissions')

class UnlockUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
"""
User model w/o password
"""
class Meta:
   model = UserModel
   #fields=('username')
   exclude = ('password','email','last_login','is_superuser','is_active','first_name','last_name','is_staff','date_joined','groups','user_permissions')
```

In views.py:

```
class LockUserView(GenericAPIView):
serializer_class=LockUserSerializer
permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

def post(self, request):
    user = User.objects.get(username=request.POST.get('username'))
    print user
    user.is_active=False;
    user.save()
    return Response({"success": "User has been locked."})

class UnlockUserView(GenericAPIView):
serializer_class=UnlockUserSerializer
permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

def post(self, request):
    user = User.objects.get(username=request.POST.get('username'))
    print user
    user.is_active=True;
    user.save()
    return Response({"success": "User has been unlocked."})
```

In urls.py

```
from rest_auth.views import (
LoginView, LogoutView, UserDetailsView, PasswordChangeView,
PasswordResetView, PasswordResetConfirmView,LockUserView,UnlockUserView
```

)

```
urlpatterns = [
    **url(r'^rest_lock/$', LockUserView.as_view(), name='rest_lock'),
    url(r'^rest_unlock/$', UnlockUserView.as_view(), name='rest_unlock'),**
]
```

The rest service that I have written is working perfectly when I posting the data of username from REST Client(like RESTEASY,POSTMAN) but when sending the value from templates of username I am able to call the service and implement it.
Can anybody say how to do this working???

Comment: Please add the error or message you're getting from Django.

Answer (score 1):

You're not sending an HTTP POST. To do that, you need to create a `<form>`. So, you should have something like this:

```
<form action="{% url 'rest-auth/rest_lock/' %}?username={{user.username}}" method="POST"
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

You'll also need to apply your style to "Submit" button.

You can learn more about HTML Forms [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp).

Comment: I have tried that way also but I am unable to call the rest service.

Comment: <td><a class="table-btn" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" /></a>
        <a href="/deactivateuser/?username={{user.username}}" class="table-btn" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" /></a>
        {% if user.is_active == True %}
        <a href="/lockuser/?username={{user.username}}"  class="table-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" /></a>
        {% else %}
        <a href="/unlockuser/?username={{user.username}}" class="table-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase" /></a>
        {% endif %}
      </td>

Comment: here lock user and unlock user rest service call is this                              <a href="{% url 'rest-auth/rest_lock/' %}?username={{user.username}}"  class="table-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" /></a>
{% else %}
<a href="{% url 'rest-auth/rest_unlock/' %}?username={{user.username}}" class="table-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase" /></a>

Comment: There is no `<form>` on your HTML code. You need it to send POST requests

Comment: hi @danilo-freitas i have tried that creating html form     <form action="{% url 'rest_lock' %}?username={{user.username}}" method="POST">
          {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>                             but the problem is when i am calling this rest service in REST Easy and any other client I am not able to lock the user and I am getting the error such as 
Lock User

POST /rest-auth/rest_lock/

HTTP 403 Forbidden
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept
Allow: POST, OPTIONS

{
    "detail": "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."
}

Comment: I don't know if you should use CSRF token in this case. Can you try without the `{% csrf_token %}` and tell me the result? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @danilo-freitas I am getting the same error when i am removing the {%  csrf_token %} tag and when I am calling the rest service

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how to solve that problem. Could you update your question with what we tried here, so other people could see it and help? I'll try to solve it later.